# Unable to resole Module '"@pnp/sp"' has no exported member 'spfi'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

I have an SPFX solution where I tried installing '`npm install @pnp/sp --save`'

Now, while using '`import { spfi } from "@pnp/sp"`' I am getting below error.

```
'"@pnp/sp"' has no exported member named 'spfi'.
```

Please guide me if anything I am missing here

Comment: Which version of `@pnp/sp` are you using? Try using v3 of PnP JS library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spfi` is available in version 3 of `@pnp/sp` library. So, try using PnP JS V3 in your SPFx solution.

You can install specific version of `@pnp/sp` using command like:

```
npm install @pnp/sp@3.6.0
```

Read more information about using V3 at: [PnP JS V2->V3 Transition](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/transition-guide/)

For a full sample project, utilizing PnP JS V3 that showcases use of `spfi`, check out this [SPFx web part sample](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-pnp-js-sample).

**Update from comments**:

Using `v3.9.0` worked for OP. You can install the this version using:

```
npm install @pnp/sp@3.9.0
```

Comment: Did not resolved with 'npm install @pnp/sp@3.6.0'. But with 3.9.0 it resolved. Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you! Installing `3.6.0` version was just an example. It is recommended to use the latest stable version of library.